# Exception while consuming records from the topic

Tags: spring-kafka

I am facing an issue while consuming the batch of events from the listener.

Some properties are maintained using bean with EXPL and some of them configured from application properties.

> ```
> Here is my consumer code : 
> @KafkaListener(topics = "#{@mybean.getInputTopic()}", groupId = "#{@mybean.getConsumeGroupId()}",
>                 properties = {
>                         "max.poll.interval.ms=#{@mybean.getMaxPollIntervalInMS()}",
>                         "max.poll.records=#{@mybean.getMaxPollRecords()}",
>                         "auto.offset.reset=#{@mybean.getAutoOffsetReset()}",
>                         "bootstrap.servers=#{@mybean.getChangeFeedBootstrapServers()}"})
>         public void onMessage(
>                 @Payload List<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> consumerRecords, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) { 
>               
>               // processing the batch of records
>                
>               }
> ```

The below error is keep on getting, and not sure what is causing this issue.

> ERROR o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer - Consumer exception
> org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Seek to current after exception; nested exception is
> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: User rebalance callback throws
> an error
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentBatchErrorHandler.java:72)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.RecoveringBatchErrorHandler.handle(RecoveringBatchErrorHandler.java:124)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1405)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1108)
> at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: User rebalance callback throws an error
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:422)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:439)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:358)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:497)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1274)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1236)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy102.poll(Unknown Source)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1246)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1146)
> at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1059)
> ... 3 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms
> expired before the position for partition my-test-topic-1 could be
> determined
>
> ```
> My configuration :
>     
>
>     > fetch.max.bytes = 10485760 //10 mb fetch.max.wait.ms = 420000 //7 min
>     > fetch.min.bytes = 5242880 // 5mb max.poll.interval.ms = 900000 //15
>     > min max.poll.records = 2500 request.timeout.ms = 320000
>     > receive.buffer.bytes = 10485760 // 10mb
> ```

Comment: Looks like some kind of timeout while the container is trying to determine the current positions during the rebalance. What version are you using? Try `setAssignmentCommitOption(AssignmentCommitOption.NEVER)` on the container properties (it should prevent the container from trying to obtain the position).

Comment: Thanks Gary..  i am using spring-boot:2.3.8 . I never encounter this issue earlier. Only when i moved to EXPL i have started seeing this issue.  All the values whichever i set, am seeing at kafka configuration during app start up

Comment: Gary.. Could you please let me know how to achieve setting the AssignmentCommitOption.NEVER in application properties at container level ? like 
spring.kafka.listener.ack-mode = MANUAL_IMMEDIATE

Comment: You can't do it in the properties; you need to inject the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?>` as a parameter to some other (any) bean definition, then `factory.getContainerProperties.set...`.

Comment: does the setting at container level will be allowed in higher versions ? As i need to remove all attributes settings at listener level and need to go for consumer factory class.

Comment: You can set it at the container level; set an `id` on the listener, set `autoStartup` to `false`; then. in an `ApplicationRunner` `@Bean`, use the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` bean - `registry.getListenerContainer(id).getContainerProperties().set...` and then `registry.getListenerContainer(id).start()`.

Comment: Or you can add a `ContainerCustomizer` to the factory.

Comment: Thank you Gary. I will implement those changes

Comment: Hi Gary.. I found the basic root cause for the issue which was all oursource topics got down.